# Why am I getting a compiler error when using 'lazy var' to create an instance?

Tags: ios, swift

In ViewController.swift - I declare a lazy var game at the beginning of the class, and still get the error

> Cannot use instance member 'cardButtons' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self is' available

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: (cardButtons.count + 1) / 2)

@IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!

var emojiChoices = ["", "", "", "" ]

@IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
    flipCount += 1
    if let cardNumber = cardButtons.index(of: sender) {
        flipCard(withEmoji: emojiChoices[cardNumber], on: sender)
    } else {
        print("Chosen card not in cardButtons")
    }
}
}
```

Here is the class 'Concentration', that I am trying to create an instance of
    import Foundation

```
class Concentration {

var cards = [Card]()

init(numberOfPairsOfCards: Int) {
  for _ in 1...numberOfPairsOfCards {
    let card = Card()
    cards += [card, card]
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a sample project from a recent Stanford iOS course.  Anyway, the syntax of your lazy var does not look correct.

change

```
lazy var game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: (cardButtons.count + 1)/2)
```

to

```
lazy var game : Concentration = { 
   return Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: (cardButtons.count + 1)/2) 
}()
```

However, accessing the value of another variable (cardButtons.count), although fine in your current code probably, could introduce an issue later if cardButtons has not been initialized before game is referenced.